# PHP filter_var bug?

Tags: php, validation, filter-var

The following code successfully validates the string "0123.250" as a valid float, when it is not. Is this a PHP bug or did I do something wrong?

```
filter_var('0123.250', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
```

Comment: `floatval` also parses that as a float, `123.25`. Did you expect the leading zero to be invalid?

Comment: Why is this an invalid float?

Comment: Looks like a float to me...

Comment: Does the leading `0` not invalidate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [**PHP documentation on float literals**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

```
LNUM          [0-9]+
DNUM          ([0-9]*[\.]{LNUM}) | ({LNUM}[\.][0-9]*)
EXPONENT_DNUM [+-]?(({LNUM} | {DNUM}) [eE][+-]? {LNUM})
```

As you can see, there is no restriction for leading zeroes, as indicated by these bits: `[0-9]*[\.]` and `[0-9]+`.

Since the page never once mentions octal, we need to assume that leading zeroes make no difference in the interpretation.

I *assume* that the exact same rules are applied for `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the fact that the String '0123.250' is not a float. I ran var_dump(is_float('0123.250')); and the return value is bool(false). However, when I ran var_dump(is_float(0123.250));the return was bool(true).

Comment: @Ali `is_float` checks the type of a variable. `'0123.250'` is no float the same way `'hello kitty'` is not a float. From the comment, you can see that the OP is worrying about leading zeroes.

Comment: but I expect `filter_var('0123.250', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);` to be false just like `filter_var('hello_kitty', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);` is false. Basically why does php make the assumption that `"0123.250"` in a number and not a string?

Comment: @Ali The idea is, that you can check *user input* to see whether it has some valid form. User input is *always* provided as a string, which is why it makes sense to parse the string and see if it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

The leading 0 just makes explicit the fact that place value for thousands is zero, which is usually implied by the absence of a digit for that place value.

If you're worrying about the fact that the leading zero is a non significant digit, I don't think PHP follows the definition that closely.